# cakePHP without domain name

Tags: cakephp, nginx, vhosts

I've set up my Raspberry Pi 2 with a nginx, php, mysql environment and installed cakePHP with composer.

Now the cakePHP landing page looks weird. I'm assuming that this issue is related to my nginx vhost configuration. (Conf with vhost works, CSS files loading)

The question is: is it possible to use cake without vhost conf?

The route is set to the respective folder:

$routes->connect('/test/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

With best regards,

Phil

Comment: landing page: http://path-to-my-rpi/test/ http://i61.tinypic.com/2dwf40h.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding these lines into my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default conf-file:

```
location /test/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/www/test/webroot/;
}
```