# cakePHP - DebugKit Toolbar not visible

Tags: debugging, cakephp

After successful installation of cakePHP via Composer no DebugKit toolbar is visible.

This is really weird cause while the installation process the following has shown:

```
- Installing cakephp/debug_kit (3.1.0)
  Loading from cache
```

config/bootstrap.php:

```
// Only try to load DebugKit in development mode
// Debug Kit should not be installed on a production system
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}
```

config/app.php:

```
/**
 * Debug Level:
 *
 * Production Mode:
 * false: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown.
 *
 * Development Mode:
 * true: Errors and warnings shown.
 */
'debug' => true,
```

Normally (manual installation), the plugin is stored in plugins-folder but it is empty.

Is there anything else I have to configure?

Kind regards,

Phil

Comment: Check error log for relevant errors. Ensure you have pdo-sqlite enabled. DebugKit by default uses a sqlite db.

Comment: Error log told me that I have to install php5-sqlite package. Since I did, no errors in error log but also no debugkit-toolbar visible.

Comment: phpinfo:

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers  mysql, sqlite

Comment: After inspecting the source-code I figured out that debug kit is enabled and running but the src-location is obviously wrong: 

<script>var __debug_kit_id = 'cdba1a7e-a768-4917-a0ca-dc79b23351ff', __debug_kit_base_url = 'http://10.0.0.4/test/';</script><script src="/test/debug_kit/js/toolbar.js"></script>

this occurs 404

I am using cakePHP without domain name and I solved CSS and JS problems with a location block in my nginx conf:

location /test/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/www/test/webroot/;
}

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040999/cakephp-without-domain-name)

Comment: You should update your question with an answer and mark it.

Answer (score 6):

Install the php5-sqlite extension. (this is for php5, use whatever version you are running)

If you are running on Ubuntu...

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

Not sure what the package name is on centos/redhat, but you can use the following command to find what the exact package name is.

```
sudo yum search php
```

Once you have the package name you can use the following to install it...

```
sudo yum install <Package Name>
```

Don't forget to restart your web server after installing. Restart the php service as well if you are using php fpm.

Comment: It's either this (I tried it and it worked), or [configuring DebugKit to work with a dedicated MySQL database](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html#database-configuration)

Answer (score 3):

This helped me:

1. `php bin/cake.php plugin assets symlink`
2. `sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite`

Answer (score 2):

The static assets are no linked to the vendor folder.

Please run the following commands:

```
cd webroot
ln -s ../vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/webroot debug_kit
```

Comment: This helped me. I did install debugkit and all the requirements, but as in @phil-in-the-blank 's case, the dubugkit was not showing. After inspecting the source code I realised that it tries to load the non-existent javascript file, and this solved it. Thank you

Comment: **UPDATE** this did help me once again, but I needed to also make sure DebugKit has a database to use, either by installing `php5-sqlite` or [configuring a dedicated MySQL database](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html#database-configuration) instead

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
bin/cake plugin assets symlink
```

[Read more...](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/plugin-shell.html#plugin-assets)